# How to get userId in observe callback

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-collections, meteor-useraccounts

I want to use observe for one of my collection on the server but I need to get userId,
I'm trying to use `this.userId` and also `Meteor.userId()` but not working! see the below code for more detail and error message
how to resolve it ?

```
Messages.find({state:"outbox"}).observe({
    added:  (doc) => {
    console.log(" observe ");
        console.log("userId : " + this.userId);  // undefined
        console.log("Meteor.userId(): " + Meteor.userId()); //  "Exception in queued task: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions."
        //.......
   }
});
```

thanks for you attention.

Comment: Is this being called from within a publish function, or just globally when the server starts?

Answer (score 2):

Within the `observe` callbacks, the `this` keyword does not point to the publication object (it points to the cursor of the related query), so it does not have a `userId` property.

You can create a closure to make the `userId` available to the function using

```js
const userId = this.userId;
```

in the body of the publication itself, and then simply use it in the callback (as `userId`).